# UIPickerView picker.reloadAllComponents() not working in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a `picker.reloadAllComponents()` call because I have altered the datasource. But I get an error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` and I know why but I want to make `UIPickerView` behave.

I want the `UIPickerView` to refresh it's list shown, AND the list to the UI based on the new criteria:

```
class ViewControllerDisplay: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource{
  //......

   var pickerData: [String] = []
   func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {  return 1  }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
      return pickerData.count
   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
      return pickerData[row] //<-- Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
       self.view.endEditing(true)
   }
   let pickerView = PREMUIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 130, width: 250, height: 300))
   pickerView.dataSource = self
   pickerView.delegate = self
```

I then do this in the on change of a text box:

```
    pickerData = []
    for node : [String:Any] in _choices{
        let _nodename = node["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let _filtername = filterField.text ?? ""
        if ((_nodename.range(of: _filtername)) != nil){
            pickerData.append(_nodename)
        }
    }
```

I then simply do this

```
   for view in (filterField.superview?.subviews)! {
        if let picker = view as? UIPickerView {
            picker.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }
```

now. What *SHOULD* happen is the UIPickerView should reset it's datasource AND redraw to the UI based on the filtered list. it doesn't. The `pickerData` list surely does get filtered. However the visual elements don't altered hence I get a `fatal error: Index out of range` error from the line in the `func pickerView` (`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`) so my question is:

How do you refresh the datasource using more than just `picker.reloadAllComponents()` and tell iOS to actually refresh the datasource?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies I made a mistake, **it does work**. The issue was elsewhere in the code regarding how I id'd the picker view. (Basically I had id'd the wrong one, one further up the page).

I'll keep the code up in case anyone wants to to a filter list based on a uipickerview

Comment: This isn't a useful answer as written. It would make more sense to delete the whole question since it won't help any future readers.

Comment: well there is a lot of posts saying you can't filter `UIPickerView` but you can, and there aren't any examples of it